# Testcafe get data from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array, testcafe

I'm trying to get data out of a multidimensional array, I tried the following:

```
await Selector('script').withText('array').textContent['item3']['item3.0']['item3.0.0']['variablesInMultiArray3'];
```

But I just get undefined instead of the data that is actually in the array.

The array looks something like this:

```
array = {
  "item0": {
      "variablesInMultiArray0": "This is some data"
  },
  "item1": {
      "variablesInMultiArray1": "This is some data"
  },
  "item2": {
      "variablesInMultiArray2": "This is some data"
  },
  "item3": {
    "item3.0": {
        "item3.0.0": {
            "variablesInMultiArray3": "Data that I need"
        }
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: Take a look at the [Create Data-Driven Tests](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/create-data-driven-tests.html).  topic. Is this way applicable to your task?

Comment: @DmitryOstashev Sadly that didn't help. I have found a way to get the data (it's not the cleanest) by putting it in a variable and `.split(',');`

Comment: The task is not clear. Could please describe how the requested array is stored on the web page (it's a property of some object, an element's property or something else)?